# IE11 - border for transparent part of png

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm setting an image for drop down using css, but in IE11 it shows border around the transparent part of image.

[image: Drop down iamge]

The css code is as follows

```
#select-id:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: url(../images/dropdown-icon.png) 100% 50% no-repeat;
  height: 48px;
  right: 125px;
  width: 50px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like that border is being applied to whatever is behind that element.

Comment: I'm sure it is for image only.

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select {background:transparent;}
```

or

```
select {opacity:0}
```